# Count of a value in a new column in R

Tags: r, count, sqldf

I have a dataframe with Transaction ID and Product Name as columns. I'm trying to create a 3rd column which gives me the count of Transaction ID's. The final dataframe should look as shown below.

```
    TID       Product        Orders         
    100       iPhone           2  
    100       Samsung          2  
    101       Lenovo           3  
    101       iPad             3  
    101       Galaxy           3  
    102       iPhone           1  
    103       HTC              1
```

I tried using the length function, but that gives me the length of the entire column but not individual TIDs.

```
df$Orders <- length(df$Tid)
```

I also tried using the sqldf function as shown. But that gives only distinct values of TID.

```
test <- sqldf("Select TID, count(TID) as Orders, Product from df Group By TID")
```

Comment: The result can be easily obtained using excel COUNTIF but it takes ages for the query to run as the dataframe contains more than 100,000 rows.

Comment: A vectorised base R approach could be `res <- table(df$TID); df$orders <- res[match(df$TID, names(res))]`

Comment: Could also try `df$Orders <- tabulate(df$TID)[df$TID]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use one of the aggregate by group functions.  Using `dplyr`, we group by the 'TID' column, create a new column 'Orders' as the number of observations within each group (`n()`) using `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(TID)%>%
  mutate(Orders=n())
#    TID Product Orders
#1 100  iPhone      2
#2 100 Samsung      2
#3 101  Lenovo      3
#4 101    iPad      3
#5 101  Galaxy      3
#6 102  iPhone      1
#7 103     HTC      1
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'Product', we create a new column ('Orders') as the number of observations within each group (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Orders:=.N, by=Product]
```

Or an option with `sqldf`, where we `left join` the original dataset with the modified dataset.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('Select * from df1
       left join(select TID, 
        count(TID) as Orders 
        from df1
        group by TID) 
        using (TID)')
    using (TID)')
#  TID Product Orders
#1 100  iPhone      2
#2 100 Samsung      2
#3 101  Lenovo      3
#4 101    iPad      3
#5 101  Galaxy      3
#6 102  iPhone      1
#7 103     HTC      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(TID = c(100L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 103L
), Product = c("iPhone", "Samsung", "Lenovo", "iPad", "Galaxy", 
"iPhone", "HTC")), .Names = c("TID", "Product"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Works like a gem. Thanks @akrun

Comment: sorry @akrun. I might have clicked on the tick by mistake.

Comment: @red No problem.  I also guessed so.

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
df1$count <- ave(df1$TID, df1$TID, FUN=length)
```

Output:

```
  TID Product count
1 100  iPhone     2
2 100 Samsung     2
3 101  Lenovo     3
4 101    iPad     3
5 101  Galaxy     3
6 102  iPhone     1
7 103     HTC     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(Orders = .N), by = Product]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're right, it does nothing, gives the same result as `.(Orders = .N)`

Comment: @akrun, Yeah, looking for a fast solution I've missunderstand the desired output, also because of missing clear input. In this case the correct answer using `data.table` is your's, with a little edit: `by = TID`